# a:active link when index page loads

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

How could I make it so when I load my index.html page it now knows that it is active and loads the respective `a:active` css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what `:active` means.
A link is `:active` if it's selected by the mouse.

You need to add `class="Current"` to the link and use that class in CSS.

Comment: Thanks I had a feeling I had do that but I was just double checking

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little Javascript that says `window.onLoad(){ *javascript to load css file*}`.